# swapping pdo in for mysql issues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've never done anything with pdo and i'm have great difficulty switching mysql_* to pdo in     my login.php file. Is there any suggestions off how to do so and make my login secure from injection?

Login.php:

```
session_start();

$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
if ($username&&$password)
{

    $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","**********","***********") or die             
    ("Couldn't connect");
    mysql_select_db ("*********") or die ("DataBase does not exist");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if ($numrows!=0)
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
           $dbusername = $row['username'];
           $dbpassword = $row['password'];
           $firstname = $row['FirstName'];
        }

        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword&&$numrows>0)
        {
           $_SESSION['name'] = $firstname;
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           header( 'Location: admin.php' ) ;
           exit;
        }
        else    
           echo "Incorrect Password!";
     }
     else 
        die ("User Doesn't Exist");
  }
  else
     die("Please try again!");
?>
```

EDITED:

dbconnect.php:

```
<?php

     $username = 'root';
     $password = '';
     $maininf = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8';
     $db = new PDO($maininf,$username,$password);

?>
```

is this correct?

Comment: U mean do you want me to convert our `CODE` to `PDO`?

Comment: Mainly i'm looking for advice to go about it since I don't know much about PDO or if it's the right way to go over mysqli_. I've been having issues trying to convert it from mysql to PDO for a while now. I keep getting a white page as it goes to login.php

Comment: The shown code currently works but I believe it to be highly at risk for injection.

Comment: @user3474741 "I keep getting a white page" That probably means you have some kind of error in your PHP file. Try turning on the "display_errors" setting in your php.ini, or check your webserver's error.log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, such a conversion is quite a simple task. You're only taking it from the wrong end. Most likely you just didn't bother to learn PDO prior using it. That turns out rather illogical acton: aren't you supposed to learn how to drive before getting your license? The same thing here - you have to learn first. So, [find yourself a tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdo%20tutorial), like one from tuts+, then read it through, then accomplish all the examples and exercises. Then try to write a simple code snippet of your own and toy with it around a bit. And the task of conversion will be piece of cake since then!

You may start from [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) right here

Just for sake of completeness.

```
session_start();

if ($_POST['password'])
{
    include 'pdo.php';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row && $row['password'] == $_POST['password'])
    {
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
       header( 'Location: admin.php' ) ;
       exit;
    }
}
die("Please try again!");
```

Comment: I think I may take this question down. It kind of makes me look rather ignorant now that I look at it. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem, mate. Everyone who answering questions on SO is wasting their time, this way or another.

Comment: I figured out the ways to connect to the database and to query the number of rows the problem is how to get info from specific rows so that it can be used for the SESSION

Comment: did you try the tag wiki I posted above? it has examples.

Comment: I looked over it a bit but I will look into it more thank you!

Comment: Added an example as your own attempt most likely would be as unclean as all first attempts are

Comment: where as pdo.php is my db connection file?

Comment: I edited my original post showing my connection code.

Comment: You don't understand. I told you not to post but to put it in a separate file. you should get one from tag wiki and store it in a file

Comment: I have this in a separate file but just to make sure I don't screw it up i copied and pasted the connection from PDO tag wiki.

Comment: yes you failed to copy the essential part. but I am afraid that questions about copying and pasting are out of scope of this site. May be on superuser@SE you may share your concerns about this matter.

Comment: no, what i have posted there is my original attempt before going with the code that is on tag wiki. I was taking my try at it with that code then decided to just go with the tag wiki connection code which I am using now.